# Android: layout_centerHorizontal vs layout_centerVertical

Tags: android

When using `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in a `Relativelayout` it does not work. However when i change it to  `android:layout="true"` it runs perfectly, why is that?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Happy" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I was experimenting on **Udacity** and tried using the a`ndroid:layout_centerVertical/Horizontal="true"` only the Horizontal layout worked and I could not understand why. I am still a beginner (1 week in) so would appreciate an explanation. TY

Answer (score 0):

When using `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` remove `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and to place horizontally center remove `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`. Aligning to side has more priority than center vertical/horizontal